# Triple Integral Function does not work when Passed in as Command Line Argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sys

I have a website where users can input their bounds of integration (sys.argv[2-7]) and their function (sys.argv[1]), and this data gets sent to a PHP function and then to Python on the backend. My python code uses the scipy function called "integrate.nquad" to numerically compute the triple integral.

The program works if the expression is written out explicitly in the argument to the right of the lambda, but does not work when passed in from the command line argument (sys.argv[1]). For example, if I  swap out the code sys.argv[1] with an expression such as x * y * z, everything works as intended.

Is there a different way to structure the scipy function that will make it all work, or do I need to look into entirely different techniques for this numeric triple integral?

```
import sys
from scipy import integrate

#numbers passed in from website via PHP function, these are used as the bounds for integration
x_lower = float(sys.argv[2])

x_upper = float(sys.argv[3])

y_lower = float(sys.argv[4])

y_upper = float(sys.argv[5])

z_lower = float(sys.argv[6])

z_upper = float(sys.argv[7])

#sys.argv[1] is the expression that users on the website input and is the function being integrated, an example would be: x*y*z
func = lambda x, y, z: sys.argv[1]


ans, err = (integrate.nquad(func,[[x_lower,x_upper],[y_lower,y_upper],[z_lower,z_upper]]))

print(ans)
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is a string.  `lambda x,y,z: x*y*z` is evaluated by the interpreter, and is not a string.

Comment: @hpaulj I just tried `func = lambda x, y, z: ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])` for a safe way of evaluating the string in that lambda, but it did not work.

Comment: You might have to use `eval('lambda x,y,z:' + 'x*y*z') `, that is, apply the `eval` to the whole `lambda` expression, not just a part.  `eval('x*y*z')` tries to find `x`, `y` etc variables.

Comment: @hpaulj `eval('lambda x,y,z:' + 'x*y*z')` worked, but I tested `eval('lambda x,y,z:' + 'sys.argv[1]')` with my website with `x*y*z` being passed in from the command line, did not work.

Comment: Don't quote `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: @hpaulj `eval('lambda x,y,z:' + sys.argv[1])` worked! Thanks so much for the help. Tested it locally because of the potential security risk. Is this application of eval hacker proof because of the lambda that is made a string inside of it?

Comment: I'm not a security expert.  It's use within a lambda, and that within the `nquad` probably limits that damage that can be done, if any.  I suppose you could test the string for a limited set of allowed characters.  You might want to do that anyways to catch unintentional errors.